Mapping face texture to liquid sim
New to blender, so bare with any bad terminology. I'm trying to recreate the face melt from Raiders of the Lost Arc, and I'm doing it using some liquid sims. For the skin, I have a high quality head scan of the person who's face I'm melting, but I cannot get the texture to map onto the liquid mesh properly. I baked the liquid sim for the skin and then exported as an alembic to get the mesh. I really just need the face to look realistic for the first few frames until the skin color takes over. My question is: How can I get the face texture to map, or how can I achieve the effect otherwise? I'm willing to provide files or more info if needed. Thanks.

Hello, not sure how you are trying to do it, have you thought about shapekeys or Animall addon?

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

We need to see some screenshots fo what you are doing and how far you've gotten, as for what we can tell here you should just be using a UV mapping to project the image to the liquid mesh from view at the onset so that the movement then 'melts' the color data.
